# How to add rewrite rule to point to file

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am trying to redirect an incoming path to a JS file. What am I not understanding about `add_rewrite_rule` that this does not work?
Yes I have flushed permalinks.

```
add_action('init', 'ssla_rewrite_init_endpoint');
function ssla_rewrite_init_endpoint() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $loader_file = SSLA_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js/ssla-loader.js';
    add_rewrite_rule( 'public/ws/([^/]*)', $loader_file, 'top' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`add_rewrite_rule` should choose where to write your rules to internal array of rewrite_rules or to .htaccess. If I understand logic behind this code `SSLA_PLUGIN_URL` is something like `http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin/`... in this case you should check your `.htaccess` (in case if you using apache), because all external rules goes there.

You can continue to debug your redirections with [debug setting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) of mod_rewrite.